# How to use MeSH Qualifiers in a PubMed search string?

Tags: literature-search, pubmed

I want to know how I combine a MeSH term with a qualifier. How do I create a search string on PubMed with it. The exact human readable question would be: *All publications with MeshTerm "Locomotion" specified by qualifier "Physiology" and all publications with "Locomtion" not specified by any qualifier.*

I am interested in the MeSH term *Locomotion*. As a search string I would write `locomotion[mh]`. The MeSH Browser tell me that one of it the qualifiers is [physiology](https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=Q000502).

I can not find the word *Qualifier* somewhere in the [PubMed help](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3827/#pubmedhelp.MeSH_Subheadings_SH) or in the available search fields.
I thought it is a synonym for *MeSH Subheadings*. But it doesn't look like.

Please see this two search queries which in my understanding should return the same number of results.
[image]

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_Subject_Headings#Qualifiers) is on my side and say that *Qualifier* and *Subheading* should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MeSH terms are divided into descriptors (or main headings) and qualifiers (or subheadings). Each descriptor can have zero or more qualifiers. A qualifier cannot exist without being attached to a descriptor.

The difference in the number of search results you have observed is because in your second search *"locomotion/physiology" [mh]* you are searching for entries which have the locomotion descriptor and physiology as a qualifier of the locomotion descriptor. In your first search *"locomotion"[mh] AND "physiology"[sh]* you are searching for entries with the locomotion descriptor and physiology as a qualifier to **any** of the MeSH terms attached to the entry.

For example [PM28410594](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28410594) is matched by your first search, but not your second.

Comment: Very tricky! ;) This means `"locomotion/physiology"[mh] OR "locomotion"[mh]` would make much more sense? Not not really! I want `locomotion/physiology[mh] OR "locomotion/ZEROQUALIFIER"` (without any qualifier). Is this possible? I could exclude (with `NOT`) explicite all other qualifiers.

Comment: `"locomotion/physiology"[mh] OR "locomotion"[mh]` is equivalent to `"locomotion"[mh]`. It will find entries with the locomotion descriptor, with or without qualifier. To achieve what you want, you could negate all the other qualifiers: `"locomotion"[mh] NOT ("locomotion/genetics"[mh] OR "locomotion/drug effects"[mh] OR "locomotion/immunology"[mh] OR "locomotion/radiation effects"[mh])`. This is admittedly quite cumbersome.